# Unable to play VEVO Video

Tags: ios, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to play VEVO Video in iPhone using LBYoutTubeView.

https://github.com/Ariharan/LBYouTubeView

Below is the VEVO Video URL
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kffacxfA7G4&feature=youtube_gdata_player

I have got this URL using the YouTube Data API.

But I am unable to play the video.

Comment: What is the error other than unable to play?

Comment: Not giving any error. Just not playing. If i will use another video url  instead of Vevo so it is playing. Have you done before for Vevo Video play.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly it's the fact that many Vevo videos are using a particular type of ad that requires Flash for playback; since there's no Flash on iOS, such videos would be unavailable through the YouTube-API in your app. Not all Vevo videos use such ads, but a large number of them fo.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `origin` parameter, even if it is just a dummy URL, seems to allow most VEVO videos to play back in an embedded iFrame player:

```
&origin=http://example.com/
```

Full iFrame example:

```
<iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='100%' height=100%' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/jCHE0Tjw6MA?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=0&autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com/' frameborder='0'>
```

Comment: @MarkusHallcyon Can you elaborate on how this doesn't work?  What video are you trying to play?